# What is the compiler of Samsung Bada?

Tags: compiler-construction, mobile, sdk, bada

Recently Samsung presented Bada platform for mobile phone.

http://developer.bada.com/apis/index.do

I can find developer materials from the above web page but, I can't find how can I compile it and what is the compiler?

This is C++ based framework and Samsung said Bada is operating system agnostic. In this case, how application developer can compile to different O.S. or different CPU.

Is anyone who had chance to work with Bada SDK then please let us know. Currently, only chosen partner can access it's SDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI Toolchain has been released:

- samsung-sourceryg++-4.4-157-arm-samsung-nucleuseabi.src.tar.bz2
- samsung-sourceryg++-4.4-41-i686-mingw32.src.zip

Answer (score 3):

You will develop and compile your bada applications through bada IDE, which is the IDE for bada development based on Eclipse. You will not develop for different OSes...you'll develop for bada, and the CPU's used by Samsung use the same architecture:ARM so there's not going to be any problems in running your app over different devices.

Comment: Thanks. So, should developer use GCC ARM compiler? Usually, private developer don't have ARM compiler as like ADS or RVCT. Also, I can't sure why Bada depends on specific CPU architecture.

Comment: As far as I checked the bada IDE it seems they use GCC ARM compiler. 
But why would you want to compile it separately when you can do that with the press of a button in bada IDE?
As I said Samsung smartphones use an ARM processors, so the bada is designed around the ARM architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't had a chance to see real Bada development environments. So, I just wonder what kind of compiler used and what is target CPU now.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the SDK and tutorial at developer.bada.com. You need to register first though.